# Add ASP.Net Identity and Entities to same database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I created a new ASP.NET MVC project, I am using code-first. I have added ASP.NET Identity to this project enabled-migrations and can see the tables in my database on sql server express.

I have a "DefaultConnection" which points to my database on sqlserver like so:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;database=worksmartDB;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now, I am confused how to add my entities to the same database via code first? Below is my structure:

**Models**

```
 Applicant
 Template
MyProjectContext(which dervies from DBContext)


public class MyProjectContext: DbContext
{
    public MyProjectContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

}

I try to enable migrations for this context but I receive the following error:

```
The context type 'MyProjectContext' was not found in the assembly 'MyProject'
```

I want to use same database for identity and entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got it to work, not sure if this is the correct method.

However,

When you add identity into a new project, you should do the following:

```
- Change public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("YourConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
Note: this connection string should point to the same database you are going to use
- Run the application in browser
- Register a user (this will create the database for you, if one does not exist)

- Now Enable-Migrations
- Update-Database
```

And this is one way of adding identity into your project.

Comment: what? so you ask a question, and then write an answer for something you didn't ask.

Comment: I don't see how, this "answer" does not relate or elaborate further on what I was asking. I have listed the thing the caused the issue at the top and just for future reference pointed out what steps I took. @AmelSalibasic

Comment: I found this useful - I was stuck in the same spot, I had updated all my "context" classes to point to the same connectionstring, but I wasn't getting the identity tables to pop up in my database. It didn't occur to me that you have to register a user in order for the tables to generate in the specified database

Comment: glad it helped :)